How to broaden the proof that the existence of a walk on a graph implies the existence of a path?
The problem
Given is the problem statement:

Let $G$ be an undirected graph and let $v,w$ be two arbitrary vertices in the graph. Prove that if there is walk from $v$ to $w$ then $G$ contains a path that contains $v$ and $w$ as its endpoints.

The problem is meant for graphs with finite vertices and paths of finite lengths, but I wanted to see how far I could go with it.
The problem was easy enough to solve when I assume that the length of a walk is finite, but I have difficulty proving it when the walk may be infinite. For example, consider the undirected graph $G = (\{0, 1\}, \{\{0,1\}\})$. Then, consider the following walk on that graph.
$$(0, \{0,1\}, 1, \{0,1\}, 0, \dots, 1).$$
We can make this walk loop an arbitrary number of time, so it feels like there is a possibility for such a walk to be infinitely long. My proof would not work for that case since it relies on the set of lengths the walk can be to be countable to be able to find a minimal walk, and that the length of the minimal walk is finite to be able to prove that it does not contain duplicate vertices.
My attempt so far
Here is the proof I wrote for walk with finite length:
Given is a graph $G = (V, E)$.
We consider the length of a walk to be the amount of edges in it. (Duplicate edges are counted as often as they occur).
Assume there is a walk from $v$ to $w$ and take $m$ to be the length of this walk.
We consider the set $\mathcal{W}$ of all walks from $v$ to $w$ of length at most $m$.
We then consider the set $\mathcal{T}$ the transversal of $\mathcal{W}$ partitioned along the equality relation “has the same length as.” (This requires the axiom of choice)
It now holds that $\mathcal{T}$ contains at least one element (the walk we assumed that existed) and at most $m + 1$, as we are only considering walks with lengths $0$ to $m$. As $\mathcal{T}$ is finite and only contains one path of each length, we can obtain a path, $W$, with the minimum length.
Then, we define $n$ as the length of $W$. We obtain vertices and edges such that $$W = (u_1, e_1, u_2, e_2, ...., u_n).$$ With vertices $u_i$ and edges $e_i$ for all $i \in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$.
We will proceed via contradiction.
Assume, for contradiction, that $W$ has duplicated vertices.
Constructing a shorter walk:
By our assumption, we may obtain an $i$ and $j$ such that $u_i = u_j$, and, without loss of generality, we may assume that $i < j$.
Consider the candidate walk $$W' = (u_1, e_1, ...., u_i, e_j, u_{j+1}, ..., u_n).$$
We claim that $W'$ is a walk on $G$ from $v$ to $w$:
Note that the first and last vertices are still $u_1 = v$ and $u_n = w$.
Therefore, $W'$ still runs from $v$ to $w$.
It remains to show that $W'$ is a walk on $G$.
$W'$ is an alternating series of vertices and edges.
$W'$ only contains vertices and edges that are in $W$.
$e_j$ is an edge between $u_i = u_j$ and $u_{j+1}$.
All other pairs of vertices and edges were already present in $W$, which is a walk.
The combination of these properties means that $W'$ is a walk on $G$ from $v$ to $w$.
Deriving the contradiction:
The length of $W'$ is less than that of $W$ as it does not contain $j - i$ of its edges, which is strictly positive. Therefore, $W$ is not the walk with the least amount of edges. That contradicts our earlier assumption. Therefore, $W$ does not have duplicated vertices.
Conclusion:
As there exists a walk from $v$ to $w$ with no duplicated vertices, namely $W$, there also exists a path with $v$ and $w$ as its endpoints.

The part with the transversal seems a little ovecomplicated. Given that a finite walk exists, there is a finite walk of minimum length (since finite lengths are well-ordered). For your main question, what is the definition of a walk?

How are you defining a possibly-infinite-length walk? I'm not sure there is a meaningful notion of one in the first place.

A sledgehammer for your initial problem is: every set of ordinals has a least member.  (I.e., the ordinals are well ordered.)  It may be that your set of ordinals doesn't contain a finite member, however, so you'd still need a way to show that not all lengths of suitable walks are infinite.

@Karl I believe that the set of all walks from $v$ to $w$ with length at most $m$ may not be finite when there are infinite edges. That is why I took the transverse. The definition of a walk in this case is “an interleaved series of vertices and edges.” Or, elsewhere, “A sequence $(v_0, e_1, v_1, e_2, . . . , e_t, v_t)$ is called a walk in $G$ (more verbosely, a walk of length $t$ from $v_0$ to $v_t$) if we have $e_i = {v_i-1, v_i} \in E$ for all $i = 1, . . . , t$.” The second definition seems to only allow for finite walks, but I'm unsure about the first.

@Deusovi, I was worried about that as well. I do not know what I could say about such walks to be honest. That is why I was wondering how to proceed in such a proof.

Yeah, the proof will hinge on the precise definition of a walk, so you should pin that down first. There are many different countably infinite total orders that you might try to use to "sequence" the vertices in a walk, but none of them have "endpoints that are connected to each other" in the way you probably need in order to express the necessary graph walk adjacency condition.

For example, in your proposed "$(0,\dots,1)$", what exactly happens in the "$\dots$"? There is an infinite sequence consisting of all positions that are finitely many steps from the front, and an infinite sequence consisting of all positions that are finitely many steps from the back, but these sequences never overlap (otherwise the whole thing would be finite), so how do you define "adjacency" between them?
